# Check for empty intersection in STL

Tags: c++, stl, set

How do I check for the empty intersection of two `std::set`s? I can use `set_intersection`, but that's unnecessarily slow, I need only `bool` answer.

Remark: `std::set` means ordered sets, they are of the same type etc.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964150/c-test-if-2-sets-are-disjoint unless question is "do we have appropriate algorithm in STL?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything wrong with just coding it yourself?

```
bool empty_intersection(const set<int>& x, const set<int>& y)
{
    set<int>::const_iterator i = x.begin();
    set<int>::const_iterator j = y.begin();
    while (i != x.end() && j != y.end())
    {
      if (*i == *j)
        return false;
      else if (*i < *j)
        ++i;
      else
        ++j;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Something like that anyway. Completely untested code.

Comment: I've been working with iterators only for 2 days and I'm happy to be able to do what I'm able to do.

Comment: OK, the algorithm above is similar to that used by set_intersection except that it immediately returns false if it finds a common element. Obviously it relies on the fact that sets are sorted, so if you increment the lower valued iterator only each time round the loop you will find all the common elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'm able to read this, I'm just not able to code such thing myself.

Comment: You can make one subtle change to remove the requirement for `operator==`: `if(*i<*j) ++i; else if(*j<*i) ++j; else return false;`